# JavaScript function writing

Tags: javascript, forms

This is what im doing:

1.

```
function getVal() {
    var asd = document.getElementById("nomyape").value
}
```

2. `getVal()`
3. `asd` (to check if the var has something)
4. `asd` is undefined

pd: "nomyape" has a value , if i do `document.getElementById("nomyape").value` I get the value, thats why i know im pretty close

What i would like to make its a function that gets 6 diferents values from differents id, so when i call it i can gather all the form data

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
var values=[];
var ids=['nomyape_!','nomyape_2',...];
function getVals(){
  for(i in ids){
    values.push(
      document.getElementById(ids[i]).value
    );
  }
}
```

use a for loop to store all values in the `values` array.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this. You need to remove var inside function which is making it a local variable.

```
var asd;
function getVal (){
 asd=document.getElementById("nomyape").value
}
```

Comment: @JaviVera Does the nomyape element exist in the DOM before you are calling the method?

Answer (score 0):

You should return the value from your function and assign it to a variable.

```
function getVal (elementId) {
   return document.getElementById(elementId).value;
}

var a = getVal("id_of_element1");
var b = getVal("id_of_element2");
```

In your version of the code you create a local variable in the function that is only visible in the function.

Assuming all of your element's have id attributes, you could pass the element id into the function to get the value of each input.

Comment: thank you so much, i knew it was easy , i thought about that but dindn t apply it

Comment: excuse me, how can i catch the return value, in order to store it on a variable for example?

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to store the return value.